# Decomposition of self adjoint elements by positive elements

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, orthogonality

> Let $a \in A$ be a self adjoint element of a $C^*$ algebra.
>
> There exists positive elements $a_+, a_-$, such that
>
> $$a=a_+ - a_{-} $$ $$a_+a_-=a_-a_+=0$$

Is the statement true?

This is used in [page 28, proposition 41.2](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00214242/document) where the author decomposes a selfadjoint operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. It's just functional calculus via the functions
$$
f_+(t)=\begin{cases} t,&\ t\geq0 \\ 0,&\ t<0\end{cases}
$$
and 
$$
f_-(t)=\begin{cases} -t,&\ t<0 \\ 0,&\ t\geq0\end{cases}
$$